Correct model.json for composite keys database relationships?
QuizQuestion has a composite key of quiz_ID,question_ID and references part of the composite key in responses as per the SQL below:
CREATE TABLE `QuizQuestions` (
  `quiz_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `question_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ordinal` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`quiz_ID`,`question_ID`),
  KEY `QuizQuestions_Questions_FK` (`question_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `QuizQuestions_Questions_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`question_ID`) REFERENCES `Questions` (`question_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `QuizQuestions_Quizzes_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`quiz_ID`) REFERENCES `Quizzes` (`quiz_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `Responses` (
  `student_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quiz_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attempt_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `question_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `student_attempt` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `teacher_feedback` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `student_feedback` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mark` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`student_ID`,`quiz_ID`,`attempt_no`,`question_ID`),
  KEY `Responses_QuizQuestions_FK` (`quiz_ID`,`question_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `Responses_QuizQuestions_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`quiz_ID`, `question_ID`) REFERENCES `QuizQuestions` (`quiz_ID`, `question_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `Responses_Students_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`student_ID`) REFERENCES `Students` (`student_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Understandably drogon_ctl create model using the model.json below creates a function entry for each relationship which causes a redefinition error in the source, but more importantly the incorrect logic.
{
    "type": "has many",
    "original_table_name": "QuizQuestions",
    "original_table_alias": "",
    "original_key": "quiz_ID",
    "target_table_name": "Responses",
    "target_table_alias": "",
    "target_key": "quiz_ID",
    "enable_reverse": false
},
{
    "type": "has many",
    "original_table_name": "QuizQuestions",
    "original_table_alias": "",
    "original_key": "question_ID",
    "target_table_name": "Responses",
    "target_table_alias": "",
    "target_key": "question_ID",
    "enable_reverse": false
},

How should composite keys be declared in model.json?

An Tao the developer of Drogon was answer my question details below:
...
this usage is not currently supported. You will need to modify the source code of drogon_ctl. The part related to creating the model is mainly in a .csp file.
If drogon_ctl is extended to handle these edge cases I will update this answer. However it shouldn't be too much trouble to reimpliment the error-some functions by hand.
